# Como limpiar campos de un formulario cuando cambio de opción en un select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Es decir al tener una opcion persona natural muestre sus campos de nombres y apellidos, pero al cambiar a jurídico y regresar a natural se hayan borrado los campos llenados inicialmente. O sea que cada vez que cambie de opción me limpie los campos de manera visual.

```
    $scope.validarPersonaC = function (){ 
        if($scope.precirifPersona!=='V' || $scope.precirifPersona!=='P' || $scope.precirifPersona!=='E'){
                $scope.primerNombrePersona="";
                $scope.segundoNombrePersona="";
                $scope.segundoApellidoPersona="";
                $scope.firmaPersonal='';
         }
    };
```

Comment: añade tu codigo, para poder orientarte

Answer (score 2):

Necesitaría ver el código, pero te pongo un ejemplo:

```
$('#idSelect').on('change', () => {
   $('#inputNombre').text('');
   $('#inputApellido').text('');
});
```

Al cambiar de opción en el `select`, el texto que contiene el `input nombre` y el `input apellido` se borra.

Si necesitas alguna respuesta concreta le sugiero que muestre lo que ha intentado y el código.

> Pd: He usado la librería JQuery